# FOR Clause Issues/Combine Row into One Column

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently my goal is that if I have three rows (a, b, z), (c, d, z),  (e,f,z). I will combine them to form one column so (a:b, c:d, e:f, z).

I have tried the code:

```
SELECT 
 d.engagement_id, 
(SELECT cf.field + ':' + cf.custom_field_value
     FROM LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_fields cf ON cf.engagement_id = d.engagement_id
     FOR XML PATH('')) [SECTORS]
FROM
    pseudo_table d
```

Currently, it says I am missing a right parenthesis before the FOR. Any ideas on why this is happening/get to my goal?

Comment: Change `+` to `||` (the Oracle concatenation operator) and try again. It may still not work, but that mistake jumps out right away.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you would use `listagg()`:

```
SELECT d.engagement_id, 
       LISTAGG(cf.field || ':' || cf.custom_field_value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cf.field) as sectors
FROM pseudo_table d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     custom_fields cf
     ON cf.engagement_id = d.engagement_id
GROUP BY d.engagement_id;
```

Comment: In Oracle you wouldn't use `+` for concatenation.